# Update a json column with entity framework 7

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem.
I have the following User class.

```
public partial class User : Audit
{
    public User(
       Id id,
       string firstName,
       string? secondName,
       string surname,
       string? secondSurname,
       string documentType,
       string documentNumber,
       string email,
       string? phone,
       DateTime? birthdate,
       string? cellPhone) : base(id)
    {
     FirstName = firstName;
     SecondName = secondName;
     Surname = surname;
        SecondSurname = secondSurname;
        DocumentType = documentType;
        DocumentNumber = documentNumber;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        Birthdate = birthdate;
        CellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

    private User(Id id) : base(id)
    {

    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? SecondName { get; private set; }

    public string Surname { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? SecondSurname { get; private set; }

    public string DocumentType { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string DocumentNumber { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string Email { get; private set; } = string.Empty;

    public string? Phone { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; private set; }

    public string? CellPhone { get; private set; }

    public Address? AddressOfBirth { get; private set; }

    public Address? AddressCurrent { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AcademicProgramUser> AcademicProgramUsers { get; private set; } = new List<AcademicProgramUser>();

    public virtual ICollection<AcademicProgram> AcademicsPrograms { get; private set; } = new List<AcademicProgram>();

    public virtual ICollection<CourseNote> CourseNoteIdTeacherNavigations { get; private set; } = new List<CourseNote>();

    public virtual ICollection<CourseNote> CourseNoteIdUserNavigations { get; private set; } = new List<CourseNote>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserAssignment> UserAssignments { get; private set; } = new List<UserAssignment>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserCategory> UserCategories { get; private set; } = new List<UserCategory>();

    public static class Factory
    {
        public static User AddPlaceOfBirth(
            Id id,
            string firstName,
            string? secondName,
            string surname,
            string? secondSurname,
            string documentType,
            string documentNumber,
            string email,
            string? phone,
            DateTime? birthdate,
            string? cellPhone,
            string country,
            string countryCode,
            string department,
            string departmentCode,
            string city,
            string cityCode,
            string direction,
            Availability? availability,
            CreatedDate? createdDate)
        {
            var user = new User(id)
            {
                FirstName = firstName,
                SecondName = secondName,
                Surname = surname,
                SecondSurname = secondSurname,
                DocumentType = documentType,
                DocumentNumber = documentNumber,
                Email = email,
                Phone = phone,
                Birthdate = birthdate,
                CellPhone = cellPhone,
                AddressOfBirth = new Address(country, countryCode, department, departmentCode, city, cityCode, direction),
            };
            user.SetAvailability(availability);
            user.SetCreatedDate(createdDate);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment of creating the user I am not asking him to save the address information because I do not want to carry out the process so long.

I want that when updating if I save the addresses.
This is my code.

```
public async Task Handle(AddUserAddressesCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _unitOfWork
            .Repository<User>()
            .GetByIdAsync(request.IdUser) ?? throw new BadRequestEx($"El id {request.IdUser} que intenta actualizar no existe");

        User.Factory.AddPlaceOfBirth(new Id(request.IdUser), user.FirstName, user.SecondName, user.Surname,
            user.Email, user.DocumentType, user.DocumentNumber, user.Email, user.Phone, user.Birthdate,
            user.CellPhone, request.Country, request.CountryCode, request.Department, request.DepartmentCode,
            request.City, request.CityCode, request.Direction, user.Availability,user.CreatedDate);

        await _unitOfWork
            .Repository<User>()
            .UpdateAsync(user);

        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

```
internal class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.Birthdate).HasColumnType("date");
        builder.Property(e => e.CellPhone).HasMaxLength(15);
        builder.Property(e => e.DocumentNumber).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.DocumentType).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(200).IsUnicode();
        builder.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);

        builder.Property(e => e.Phone).HasMaxLength(20);
        builder.Property(e => e.SecondName).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.SecondSurname).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.Property(e => e.Surname).HasMaxLength(50);
        builder.OwnsOne(address => address.AddressCurrent,
            ownedNavigationBuilder => ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson());
        builder.OwnsOne(address => address.AddressOfBirth,
            ownedNavigationBuilder => ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson());

        #region "AUDIT"
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasConversion(
            e => e!.Value,
            value => new Id(value));

        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasConversion(
            CreatedDate => CreatedDate!.Value,
            value => CreatedDate.CreationDate());

        builder.Property(e => e.LastModifiedDate).HasConversion(
            LastModifiedDate => LastModifiedDate!.Value,
            value => LastModifiedDate.CreationDate());

        builder.Property(e => e.Availability)
            .HasConversion(
            e => e!.Value,
            value => new Availability(value));

        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedByUser).IsRequired(false);
        builder.Property(e => e.LastModifiedByUser).IsRequired(false);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

At the time of updating the user does not save the json with the update.

You can check my repository if you want. https://github.com/JhotamsDeveloper/MSschool (It's a learning project)

I have made different update combinations and it does not work for me, however, adding this method when creating the user does work.